# React Native CLI failed to determine Android project configuration

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to build my android project but I'm facing a configuration error. 
Previously I built an app bundle, but after that, I'm receiving the following error.

I already deleted node_nodules and tried "yarn install" but the error persist.

```
    D:\ReactNative\Mapin\android>gradlew assembleRelease
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 10 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\ReactNative\Mapin\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 206

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> React Native CLI failed to determine Android project configuration. This is likely due to misconfiguration. Config output:
  [root:D:\ReactNative\Mapin\android, reactNativePath:D:\ReactNative\Mapin\node_modules\react-native, dependencies:[:], commands:[], assets:[], platforms:[:], haste:[providesModuleNodeModules:[], platforms:[]], project:[:]]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
```

Comment: In our case, we have an atypical structure since we added React Native to an existing Android application years ago. After changing the main app/module name to `app` and moving the entire Android application into a `android` sub directory, things started to work without an issue. 

I'm sure you could configure things to make the non-standard structure work, which we were doing previously, but with the advent of autolinking, the extra hoop jumping didn't feel warranted. So we caved to the defaults and are moving forward now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed follow the following:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@3.0.3
yarn add react-native@0.61.5
Removed "--quiet" from npx.cmd in native_modules.gradle
cd android && gradlew clean
```

native_modules.gradle can be found in:

```
${PROJECT_FOLDER}/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle
```